# How do I put two SlickGrid grids on one page?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

How do I put two SlickGrid grids on one page?  Just having one slickgrid (jquery control) requires a lot of particular commands and the use of a nameless function (it seems).  So what if I want two controls or more on one page?

there is something about the jquery function declaration:

$(function () {

that seems to prevent this from workinging.  It is not really a function declaration.  So there cannot be a $(function2 () { 
for the second grid.

By just duplicating the content for a second grid in the example code, I get somethnig that is umproductive.  Can you see where I go wrong?

```
enter code here
```

Well, that did not work.  I will have to ftp the code and post a link to it on a web site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your issue. You can create as many instances of `Slick.Grid` as you wish:

```
var grid1 = new Slick.Grid("#firstGrid", someData, someColumns, someOptions);
var grid2 = new Slick.Grid("#secondGrid", otherData, otherColumns, otherOptions);
```

Comment: I have tried everythign I can think of and the second grid comes up empty.  I will start with something simple.  I will add the example3-editing.html example code here with a simple duplication of the second grid if I cannot get it working...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with idbehold's answer. You can create and display multiple slickgrids on one page.

eg. Your .js file must resemble

```
var grid1;
var data1=[];
var columns1=[ //relevant code ];

var grid2;
var data2=[];
var columns2=[ //relevant code ];

var options={ //relevant code }; //You can also create separate options for each grid,
                                 //but take care to include those as arguments when                                                                   
                                 //initializing the grid.

$ function() {
// relevant code
grid1 = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid1", data1, columns1, options); //or options1
grid2 = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid2", data2, columns2, options); //or options2
// more code
}
```

Note: Please take care to close all the brackets correctly. Above is just to show the way your code should be. I have tried using such kind of code successfully.